# Sorting fragments in ListView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I am currently using a LinearLayout to show a list of fragments views, but I want to be able to sort them by one of the parameters of the fragment view.  It happens to be a text field but it is within a constraint layout.  The constraint layout is the container for the fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/clPostcode"
    ... >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPostcodeName"
        ... />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPostcodeCity"
        ... />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this fragment is placed inside a simple linear layout using the fragment manager/fragment transaction.  I want to sort the fragments in the list by the tvPostcodeName field.  the user will periodically add new elements to the list and I want them in numerical order.

the TransactionManager cannot put them in an ArrayAdapter to be sorted.

Is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by sub classing the ArrayAdapter.  I had to write my own constructor to create the fragments using the FragmentManager.

```
public FragmentManager(... T[] fragments){

    FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++){
        Fragment fragment = fragments[i];
        //Do what ever you need to do to your fragment instance
        ft.add(fragment, fragment.getSomeUniqueString());
        mObjects.add(fragment);
    }
    ft.commit();
}
```

and getView as:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Fragment fragment = mObjects.get(position);
    ... // checking left off to save space
    view = fragment.getRootView();
    ... // checking left off to save space
    return view;
}
```

And then sorting has to know about the structure of the fragment class.

I think it can also be done by only keeping a list of the SomeUniqueString and using this to findViewByTag in the FragmentManager.  That will be next problem.